# Returning error message if function/procedure fails to execute

Tags: pascal

In SQL I learned to check for errors in every query that my script executes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM something";
$result=msqli_query($conn, $query);
if(!$result){
    echo "There is something wrong with ", $query;
} else {
//Proceed as normal
}
```

So I figured it might be a good idea to implement the same idea into my pascal program as well. But I don't know how to check for if a part in the program fails to execute or not. I was thinking of something like this

```
if (//a function/procedure could not execute) then
    WriteLn('Error!')
else
    //Proceed with other functions/procedures;
```

In SQL, `!$result` means `mysqli_query` returned `false` because it couldn't execute the query, but I don't know how to do that to pascal functions/procedures...Normally if a function or procedure fails to execute the program will just crash with an error in the terminal, it won't return a `false` value like in SQL for me to catch and manipulate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Are you saying you need help understanding how an `if` statement works in Pascal? Or how Pascal function/procedure calls work? Or something else?

Comment: @lurker I've updated the question. Hope that explained my problem a bit better

Comment: In Pascal, it's not "normal" for a function or procedure "to just crash" on failure. There may be some library functions that intentionally raise exceptions, in which case you need to use exception handling (google it). In pascal only a `function` returns a value as a function. A `procedure` can only return values through `var` arguments. But in either case, you would just check the return as you might expect. If you have a boolean result, `var success: boolean;`, then `success:= myFunctionCall(...);` then `if success then...` (or `if not success then ...`).

Comment: If you wrote a Pascal function that just crashes on failure, you need to examine it as to why it crashes. If you are using a library call that you think just crashes on failure, look up the documentation for that library call and find out what they actually do on failure. If it says it raises an exception, then look up "Pascal exception handling".

Comment: Which Pascal implementation are you using?

Comment: `$result=msqli_query($conn, $query);` works because `msqli_query` is written to return true if it succeeds and false if it does not. If you want that same behavior in your Pascal functions, you need to write them the same way, where they return a boolean that indicates success or failure. Any basic Pascal tutorial should show you how to return a value from a function.